# Redirect if query string match on nginx

Tags: nginx

How can I do a redirect if there's a query string on nginx? Additionally, the query string must not come with a trailing slash before, for example:

www.url.com?id=xxx

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) does what you want